# MathJax formatted text being shoved to the right side of DIV and overflowing bounds

Tags: html, css, wordpress, mathjax

I've got MathJax installed on my WordPress blog (currently via a plugin, but the results are the same if I manually install the script in header/footer) and the following

```
\[ \mbox{P+Q=R where:} \]

\[ \frac{s=y_{P}-y_{Q}}{x_{P}-x_{Q}} \]

\[ x_{R}=s^{2}-x_{P}-x_{Q} \mbox{ mod p and } -y_{P}+s(x_{P}-x_{R})\mbox{ mod p} \]

\[ \mbox{Note that s is the slope of the line through P and Q} \]



\[ \mbox{And 2P=R where:} \]

\[ s=\frac{3x_{P}^{2}+a}{2y_{P}}\mbox{ mod p} \]

\[ x_{R}=s^{2}-2x_{P}\mbox{ mod p and }y_{R} = -y_{P}+s(x_{P}-x_{R})\mbox{ mod p} \]
```

Is rendering all scrunched up on the right side of the content area (and overflowing it in at least one place). I can't for the life of me figure out why...

[image]

Here's a [link](http://codinginmysleep.com/rubber-ducking-elliptic-curve-cryptography/) to the affected page if some wizard with a deeper knowledge of CSS than mine can make use of the page source.

**Update:** *Everything appears to render properly when logged out, so the problem seems related to WordPress' topbar.*

Comment: I can't even see the problem on chrome

Comment: Odd given that the above screenshot was taken in chrome :P

Comment: as in, the render in the screenshot is not showing. only the text that you posted here

Comment: Venturing a guess: does a refresh help? Timeouts while downloading its components can throw MathJax's calculations off -- leading to such results. A refresh usually fixes these since the MathJax files remain cached.

Comment: @kennypu the old copy of the page (without mathjax libs) may be cached on the server, let me clear the cache real quick.

Comment: OK this is odd, going to edit the Q to reflect this, but it renders properly when logged out, seems to be a side effect of being logged in to WordPress that fubars the render...

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that, the `MathJax_Display` div on those lines have a `text-align: center` style on them. removing that style will left align the text.